# jquery form plugin and show content of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery form plugin and i try show the result when i submit my form in one div but no get result

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{ 
jQuery('#base64').ajaxForm(
{ 
dataType:'json', 
success:edit64,
target: '#htmloutput' 
});
});

function edit64(datasend64)
{ 
if (datasend64.edit_result64=="ok")
{
jQuery('#htmloutput').fadeIn('slow'); 
}
}
</script>
```

I donñt know if i put all well or no , i try mant times and no get the result of form inside div , only show nothing

```
<div id="htmloutput" style="display:none;"></div>

<form action="admin_db_edit.php" name="base64" id="base64" method="post">
<input type="text" name="value_base64" value="" class="db_edit_fields" />
<input type="hidden" name="send64" value="ok" />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send" class="db_edit_submit" />
</form>
```

Thank´s for the help , regards

Comment: Did you look at the documentation on "callback"? http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

Answer (score 0):

First... you have no url specified for the form. second, try adding a function to handle the error case. This can help you understand if the issue is happening on the client or the server.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#base64').ajaxForm({
    url: ????
    dataType: 'json',
    success: edit64,
    error: onError,
    target: '#htmloutput'
  });
});

function edit64(datasend64) {
  if (datasend64.edit_result64 == "ok") {
    jQuery('#htmloutput').fadeIn('slow');
  }
}

function onError(response, error, reqObj){
  alert(response);
}
```

Comment: he doesn't need a url since he set the `action` DOM attribute on his form

Comment: He's not capturing the post-callback... That's why hes not seeing the callback

Comment: maybe I should have not posted on this question. Is the post callback for jQuery forms not 'success'?

Comment: Nevermind I see it. He's making the same error I did. Assuming the ajaxForm call is the same as the ajax call. You're right that he needs to pass a function to the call that handles the callback

Comment: i use json for verificate one if in php and need show also contebt in div , the problem it´s that use json and show code in div created from php

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to send the data somewhere, you are probably missing the url attribute(as shown in the offical docs: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object)

however, trying to log the datasend64 value will help to determind if the function have been called or not. so... in your code:

```
  function edit64(datasend64)
  { 
     console.log(datasend64);

     if (datasend64.edit_result64=="ok")
     {
         jQuery('#htmloutput').fadeIn('slow'); 
     }
  }
```

if a result is shown in the developer console - you can watch the object and seek for your values (if there are any at all). if you don't see anything - the success event havn't occoured (again, i think you are missing the url parameter)